# I can not set the date format

Tags: angular, angular-material

In datepicker, the date is displayed like this `July 31, 2019`. But the model conveys committed in a different way.

```
ng-reflect-model="Wed Jul 31 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0"
```

How can this be fixed on DD.MM.YY? I tried this, but it doesn't work.

html:

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp" [(ngModel)]="date" placeholder="Date" required>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #dp></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

ts:

```
  import * as _moment from 'moment';
  const moment = _moment;


  date = moment().format('DD.MM.YY')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can convert date into specified format by using the moment.js

```
let oldDate = new Date(); // you can specify input date which you want to convert.
let newDate = moment(oldDate).format('DD.MM.YY')
```

I hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Angular Material documentation for `mat-datepicker` (Source: [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#setting-the-selected-date))

> The datepicker will not accept date strings formatted in user format such as "1/2/2017" as this is ambiguous and will mean different things depending on the locale of the browser running the code.

You can only pass ISO 8601 formats to the datepicker (Eg. `2019-07-31` or `2019-07-31T04:43:04.981Z`)

If you want that format for the backend or for display purposes elsewhere, you can always make use of moment to format the dates to your desired format.

```
let date = new Date();
let formattedDate = moment(date).format(DD.MM.YYYY);
```